# Por que preciso adicionar um parênteses em múltiplas condições de um operador ternário?

Tags: php, operadores

Vamos partir dos seguintes valores:

```
$foo = 1;
$bar = 1;
```

Como a extra condição colocada no `else` sem os parênteses, o resultado não condiz com a intenção do operador:

```
echo ($foo && $bar) ? 'Foo Bar' : ($foo) ? 'Foo' : ''; //Foo
```

Mas quando os parênteses são adicionados, o resultado é exibido de acordo com a intenção do operador:

```
echo ($foo && $bar) ? 'Foo Bar' : (($foo) ? 'Foo' : ''); //Foo Bar
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Questão de precedência e associação de operadores, a linguagem encontra uma situação que um operando pode pertencer a um operador ou outro, ela tem que tomar uma decisão a qual operador aquele operando será usado, e ela [documentou como ela decide](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).

Os parenteses são para mudar a precedência, afinal eles têm precedência sobre quase tudo na linguagem. Isto não está ali na documentação de precedência (PHP é assim, tudo feito pela metade), alguém deve achar que não é um operador.

Podemos entender a precedência, a grosso modo, como uma forma do compilador por parenteses em lugares específicos, então pela regra adotada o que você escreveu é na verdade isto:

```
echo (($foo && $bar) ? 'Foo Bar' : $foo) ? 'Foo' : '';
```

Quando você tem dois operadores com mesma precedência, e claro que o mesmo operador tem a mesma precedência, então tem que olhar a associação, e no caso do operador condicional (não gosto do termo ternário porque isto é circunstancial e poderia haver outros ternários que fazem outra coisa) a associação é da esquerda para a direita, então ele tenta completar sua execução com os três operandos que ele encontrar o mais diretamente possível, portanto assim que ele encontra um simples operando após o `:` ele considera que o operador está completo e encerra sua análise ali mesmo.

Aí todo o resultado do primeiro operador condicional será o primeiro operando do próximo operador condicional usado, o que provavelmente (neste caso certamente) dará problema porque o primeiro operando deste operador tem que sempre resultar em um booleano (não é o caso neste código, ele resulta em *string* ou número, embora em uma linguagem de tipagem fraca isto pode ser considerado como um booleano, mas certamente o que você espera, a não ser por coincidência, e aí achar o *bug* não é nada fácil).

Com os parênteses você ajusta isto e ele passa considerar que o resultado de todo o operador condicional colocado em seguida é que deve ser usado como terceiro operando do primeiro operador e portanto o que deve resultar se o primeiro operador der falso.

```
echo ($foo && $bar) ? 'Foo Bar' : ($foo ? 'Foo' : '');
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Operator/PrecedenceConditional.php).

Tirei um par de parênteses desnecessários. Deixei os outros porque eles ajudam a legibilidade, mas poderia retirar sem mudar o resultado porque a precedência do `&&` é maior que do `? :`

Quando precisa aninhar operadores condicionais recomenda-se deixar até mais claro separando cada parte em uma linha ou preferir pelo menos um deles como `if`.

Comment: Obrigado pela excelente explicação @Maniero.